# Case Insensitive Compare with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, string-comparison, fluentvalidation

I have been unsuccessful in implementing case insensitive comparing using [Fluent Validations](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). I am just trying to compare two email fields and ignoring case.

The rules in place currently are:

```
RuleFor(x => x.EmailAddress).NotEmpty().Length(5, 200).EmailAddress();
RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmEmailAddress).NotEmpty().Equal(x => x.EmailAddress).WithMessage("Emails must match");
```

To add the requirement to be case insensitive I considered passing a comparer with the equal call but that does not seem to work.

```
RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmEmailAddress).NotEmpty().Equal(x => x.EmailAddress, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).WithMessage("Emails must match");
```

Ideally, I would like to have a case insensitive comparison done on client side if possible. Will anyone be able to provide guidance on how to accomplish this?

The NuGet packages I am currently using are:

```
<package id="FluentValidation" version="5.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="FluentValidation.MVC4" version="5.1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of the .Must() extension method, with the overload that accepts both the parent object and the property being validated like so:

```
RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmEmailAddress)
    .NotEmpty()
    .Must((x, confirmEmailAddress) => x.EmailAddress.Equals(confirmEmailAddress, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .WithMessage("Emails must match");
```

This is only supported on the server-side, however, as per the [documentation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc):

> Note that FluentValidation will also work with ASP.NET MVC's
>   client-side validation, but not all rules are supported. For example,
>   any rules defined using a condition (with When/Unless), custom
>   validators, or calls to Must will not run on the client side. The
>   following validators are supported on the client:
>
> - NotNull/NotEmpty
> - Matches (regex)
> - InclusiveBetween (range)
> - CreditCard
> - Email
> - EqualTo (cross-property equality comparison)
> - Length

Comment: This looks to pass initial tests server side. It looks like client side validation is lost here. Is that accurate? Will I need to write additional custom .js and .css to enhance this?

Comment: @Jerode: I'm afraid so, you could have a look at the client-side EqualTo built-in validator. I have to admit I'm a server-side kinda guy so I'm not too familiar with those validators myself.